# Use of OpenGL to make 3D Cupboard Image using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl, graphics

I have to draw cupbaord image like below using visual studio c++ by using OpenGL and I dont have much of an idea on how to do this. Where should I start?

[image: cupboard]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Search the web for OpenGL/DirectX (the first one should be easier for you), noone will supply you with a code if you didn't actually do anything. You can add a link to the graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume for a short moment that the cupboard should be 2 dimensional (I cant believe that your teacher wants you to start 3d development without giving you an introduction first). This simplifies things alot. While you could also draw 2d shapes with OpenGL or DirectX I wouldnt recommend you any of those frameworks, as these have a steep learning curve especially for a beginner.

It would have been nice to know, whether you (and your class) have worked with a specific GUI framework before. If not Im afraid to tell you that you will have to get into one. [QT](http://qt-project.org/) is one of the most commonly used in C++ and I would advice you to you this one, as it provides a clean abstraction and you wont have to deal with kind of lowlevel functions like they appear in win32.

Nonetheless which one you choose, nearly every has some component allowing you to draw arbitrary (2D) stuff. In QT this is done by implementing a custom Widget. Here is a tutorial on this matter: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1174421&seqNum=2

As I assume that your cupboard should actually be a more or less fancy grid I can assure you that this is kind of simple. A little hint: rectengular polygons and for loops.

Comment: Don't be afraid of win32 or any library, and don't promote that fear. Thus is the main reason win32 is 'hard' in my experience...

Comment: @jheriko I have worked with a bunch of gui libraries (including win32) and Im quite sure that I can have my own opinion. Win32 is definetely not the right thing for a beginner. Without proper abstraction (which QT is btw) win32 is simply pain in the ass for anything that goes beyond a simple label and I dont think he as a beginner has the time (nor the skill) to write such an abstraction layer.

Comment: sure you are entitled to your opinion and there i some truth to it but I wouldn't qualify win32 as hard - the broad pattern of manipulating objects through handles is very common and concpetually equivalent to an OO interface (though it need not be well made, just like an OO interface). i've seen considerable damage from such opinions over the years... not just win32, but even C/C++ and things like SPUs or even just rendering or audio specialities as disciplines so I like to actively discourage it where possible...

Answer (score 0):

I weakly recommend the classic 'NeHe' tutorials http://nehe.gamedev.net/ they demonstrate some poor code but do the job and are popular enough that you can find help with them specifically

Tackle it like any problem too... you can make an app? so you know you need an entry point, right? You want to show an image? Load it into memory etc.... google become much more helpful for those kinds of targeted problems. :)

Comment: i think he dont want to load image of cupboard into memory but just want to draw an cupboard image.i think so

Comment: Those two things are not separable, although you can certainly hide some in a function or library... eg stb_image.c